# Is it possible to include one cocoapod into another?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I have a cocoapod which has dependency on another cocoapod, however I do not know how to add this dependency. I am unable to find any online tutorials for the same. Kindly let me know if there is a way we can add one pod into another

Answer (score 1):

you have to add below in you cocoapod podspec file:

```
spec.dependency 'SomeOtherPod'
```

Comment: Did that but do v also need an entry in the podfile?

Comment: no if you are adding in podspec file of your framework. Then there is no need to add in podfile.

Comment: I don't see a way to specify path in podspec file, I was only able to do so in podfile, how does then one know where to include the pod from?

Comment: If you add your dependent pod in podspec file then there is no need to worry about to add in podfile.